# Python for loop TRUE or FALSE stops processing

Tags: python

Ive got the following for loop that iterates over a list checking each element to see whether it exists in another list.

When the return TRUE and return FALSE statements re included it only iterates over the first elements in the list and then stops.

If I remove the return statements it iterates over all items and prints. Im confused.

```
def delphiresults():
    # List of producers performing push actions in delphioracle
    producersoracle = delphioracle_actors()
    producersdb = db_connect.getProducers()
    print(producersdb)
    for producers in producersdb:
        prod = producers[0]
        print(prod)
        if prod in producersoracle:
            print("found")
            return True
        else:
            print("not found")
            return False
```

Comment: You're confused that `return` returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return will exit the function, so your for loop stops executing after the 1st iteration.

Perhaps you want to store these boolean values in some list and return that after completing the loop?

```
def delphiresults():
    # List of producers performing push actions in delphioracle
    producersoracle = delphioracle_actors()
    producersdb = db_connect.getProducers()
    print(producersdb)
    found = []
    for producers in producersdb:
        prod = producers[0]
        print(prod)
        if prod in producersoracle:
            print("found")
            found.append(True)
        else:
            print("not found")
            found.append(False)
    return found
```